# Java SocketException Error

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to understand how an API works to develop using it. 
I need to connect in that API and authenticate.

The authentication method is POST.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0/Login/Autenticar");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.addRequestProperty("token", "77b495072cf8b35a0b187218721871e4790dd6b92asxald6a29");

    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code: " + code);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at TestandoAPIOlhoVivo.main(TestandoAPIOlhoVivo.java:19)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wild guess here, are you running this on a corporate network behind a proxy? Specifically in a Windows domain?

Comment: No Andrew, I was running this code on my home wireless network. I don't have proxies. My computer runs Windows  7.